# How on list item pass Data to another Activity?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have in my php a request that get hospital patients information, in my list Item i have then patients names. I'd like to know, how can get the data that belong to one of the Patient Item clicked, appaering in a new activity ?

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more specific here...

Comment: @keyboardSmasher I understand, the question has its problems. But your sarcastic comment does not really improve the situation, you are just littering (even more) the site by posting things like that IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extras to an intent, then inside of the new activity you can pull those extras out.

**Inside the first Activity:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeOtherActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(i);
```

**Inside the other activity:**

```
String mValue = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
// mValue will now be set to the string "value"
```

You can add more than one extra if you need to and you can always look them up using the same key that you added them with.

Comment: Got to ad this line on my XML listView "android:clickable="true"

Comment: @AlexGoncalves no, you need to use ListView.setOnItemClickListener() to get callbacks when your list items receive clicks. [This Page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) in the docs covers the basic usage of ListView. The very last thing in their example code is the setOnItemClickListener()

Comment: And still 0%. That's a travesty, after you deciphered his question AND came up with the answer. I'd take a little humor and sarcasm over that any day.

Comment: Nu 2 to Stack, no need to add to Android too + Square not native English close to an hundred autistic. Do not know where to had the diserved point ?*